# Class Array Error - ''Type of expression is ambiguous without more context''

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm pretty new to coding Swift, so please excuse me if this error can be simply fixed!

I created an array, and created a class for each variable. My class looks like this -

```
class name {
    var Name: name?
}

class subject {
    var Subject: subject?
}

class grade {
    var Grade: grade?
}
```

And my Array is the following -

```
var arr = [

    [
        name: "Koester",
        subject: "Science",
        grade: "9A"
    ],
    [
        name: "Koester",
        subject: "Science",
        grade: "9B"
    ]
]
```

On the Line 8 of the second block of code, "[" I get an error that says - 
 "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

I've tried checking all the other posts related to this "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error, but I couldn't find one that was directly related to a variable array, and it seems like I'm the first one that's getting the error inside the array itself.

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you're trying to actually achieve? Are you trying to store an array of dictionaries? Btw you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is UpperCamelCase for types and lowerCamelCase for variables. Also why use the json tag, are you actually trying to parse a JSON? (That array is not a valid JSON though).

Comment: `name: "Koester",`: You meant `"name": "Koester",`? That's unclear.

Comment: Unrelated: class names should be Capitalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question is your requirement is you need a class which should have properties which will store the student data and you need to add that data into `Array`.

Check below code:

Create a calls For `StudentDetail` like:

```
class StudentDetail {

    //Create Student Properties
    var name: String?
    var subject: String?
    var grade: String?

    //Initialise properties this way
    init(name: String, subject: String, grade: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject
        self.grade = grade
    }
}
```

Now create a class object like:

```
var user1Detail = StudentDetail(name: "Koester", subject: "Science", grade: "9A")
var user2Detail = StudentDetail(name: "Koester", subject: "Science", grade: "9B")
```

Now you can store it this way in `Array`:

```
var arr = [StudentDetail]()
arr.append(user1Detail)
arr.append(user2Detail)
```

Now your `arr` will have student detail and you can access properties of it.

Hope this will help.